# import of d3 breaks exports

Tags: d3.js, webpack

I am writing library and i have exports like this:

```
export function a(){ ... }
```

And using these functions as `graphs.a()`

After i added

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
```

if i use library with

```
<script src="graphs.js"></script>
```

all is ok and module have functions, but when i use in node.js

```
import * as graphs from './graphs.js'
global.graphs = graphs
```

module 'graphs' contains no functions

```
Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
__esModule: true
__proto__: Object
```

Module using `<script>`

```
Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
address_graph: (...)
address_sankey: (...)
query: (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
__esModule: true
get address_graph: ƒ ()
get address_sankey: ƒ ()
get query: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: do `console.log(graphs)` to debug

Comment: If after `import * as d3 from 'd3'` write `window.d3 = d3` in browser `console.log(d3)` will be  `Module {…} ` when jquery or lodash are functions.
Maybe it might be useful

Answer (score 1):

The import syntax only works if you're using a module bundler like Webpack or Rollup, or if you are using `<script type="module">`. What is your build system like?

If you could share an example repository that reproduces the behavior, it would help folks be able to debug.

Typically with Webpack, the build injects a `<script>` tag automatically into the HTML that points to the built bundle, so you should not need to include the  `<script>` tag yourself. If you do, it might introduce conflicts or not work correctly.

If you want to import the library in Node, it needs to be built to a CommonJS module (that should be an output option of Webpack).

Comment: Here is my library repository [repository](https://github.com/bitquery/graphs)

It is used via npm package or optionally via cdn

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I don't see any `index.html` there. How can I run it to reproduce the problem you described originally?

Comment: I made a working example in [codepen](https://codepen.io/ivanov_andrey17/pen/GRqbKXZ). 
It is more difficult to reproduce the problem, you need to clone this [repo](https://github.com/bitquery/widgets) and this [repo](https://github.com/bitquery/explorer/tree/npminstallgraphs). After `npm install` in widgets and `npm install` in explorer, `rails s` to start and go to [link](http://localhost:3000/ethereum/address/0xa09871aeadf4994ca12f5c0b6056bbd1d343c029/graph?theme=dark). More info can be found in app/javascript/packs/application.js